# python dynamic from module import function by string

Tags: python, import

The origin code is(simplify for example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from utils.func_a import func_a as _func_a
from utils.func_b import func_b as _func_b
def func_a():
    _func_a()

def func_b():
    _func_b()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_a()
```

now I only called func_a, or maybe func_b, it depends on configuration.

so I want to dynamic do from ... import ..., such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def func_a():
    _func_a()

def func_b():
    _func_b()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keys = ['func_a']
    for k in keys:
        mod_n = func_n = k
        from utils.<mod_n> import <func_n> as _<func_n>   # TODO
    func_a()
```

but I don't know to how to implement it?

What I have thought is do import in func_X():

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def func_a():
    from utils.func_a import func_a as _func_a
    _func_a()

def func_b():
    from utils.func_b import func_b as _func_b
    _func_b()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_a()
```

but this way will do import every time when call function.

---

Supplement:

I have tried `__import__` / `importlib`, but can't implement this condition

Comment: With regards to your last example: imports are cached, so the modules you mention will not be imported every time you call the functions. [Read more here.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: Take a look at the [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__import__` is a builtin function which takes the module name as a string and returns the module as an object. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__):

> ```
> __import__(name[, globals[, locals[, fromlist[, level]]]])
> ```
>
> The function imports the module `name`, potentially using the given `globals` and `locals` to determine how to interpret the name in a package context. The `fromlist` gives the names of objects or submodules that should be imported from the module given by `name`.

Comment: I have tried `__import__`/`importlib`, but can't implment this

Comment: Can you explain why you can't implement it?

Comment: get module by __import__, and get func by getattr, but func is a variable. It can't implment is the second example

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Why doesn't it work to use `__import__('utils.'+mod_n,  fromlist=[func_n])`?

Comment: thank you, I saw the entire `__import__` doc and found the usage.

Answer (score 0):

before I ask the question, I have tried `__import__` and `importlib`, but can't write out the code.

thanks for @machine-yearning, I read the entire doc of `__import__`.

this is my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
def func_a():
    _func_a()

def func_b():
    _func_b()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keys = ['func_a']
    for k in keys:
        mod_n = func_n = k
        _temp = __import__('utils.'+mod_n, fromlist=[func_n])
        _func = getattr(_temp, func_n)
        new_func_n = '_{0}'.format(k)
        setattr(sys.modules[__name__], new_func_n, _func)

    func_a()
```